Pagination not working in Angular | SwiperJS
I am trying to use swiper.js and its pagination is not working, the slider is working but not pagination, here is the code.
ts
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      breakpoints: {
        767: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
        },
      },
    });
  }

html
<div class="swiper swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">IMAGE 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">IMAGE 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">IMAGE 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">IMAGE 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">IMAGE 5</div>

      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

The slider is working and only two slides are being shown but the pagination isn't.

The initialization code of an external library should usually run outside the Zone.js Angular's zone in order to avoid unneeded change detection runs. See here on how to do that: https://angular.dev/best-practices/zone-pollution#run-tasks-outside-ngzone Just placing the new Swiper init code inside runOutisdeAngular callback would be enough. Not sure if that will also fix the issue, but it will definitely be a performance gain :)

@davidlj95 Thanks for the tip, I have updated my code but as you said it may not fix the issue, it didn't.

Here is a working example of the implementation of Swiper Element with pagination on : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jnujah?file=src%2Flib%2Fswiper.directive.ts,src%2Fmain.ts
(WebComponent mode is the recommended way to include it in an Angular app. See https://swiperjs.com/angular).

Glad to hear it ;)

So I solved the solution by seeing Lucas answer, I had to add
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';

register();

in the main.ts file

I think you are missing one attribute in the pagination to render the bullets or pages. Could you please try something like this ?
  pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            renderBullet: function (index, className) {
                return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
            },
            clickable: true,
        },


Still not working

Glad that Lucas helped.
